# How can I bind events to the timeslot in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am looking to bind to the double-click event on a timeslot so I can show an alert. This is the code I am currently using

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2014-11-12',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, 
    events: [
        {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2014-11-01'
        }
    ],
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.bind('dblclick', function() {
            alert("dblclick event");
        });
    }
});
```

It uses the `eventRender` option to bind the double-click event for the events, and that works.  But I want to bind to the double-click event on a time slot to show the alert above. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for your suggest. That's my mistake and I have update code. but my above issue is not still resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is a solution for this issue by using dayClick option:

```
    var delay = 300, clicks = 0, timer = null;

    dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

             clicks++;  //count clicks

                 if(clicks === 1) {

                       timer = setTimeout(function() {

                       alert('Single Click'); //perform single-click action

                       clicks = 0;  //after action performed, reset counter

                             }, delay);

                  } else {

                         clearTimeout(timer);  //prevent single-click action

                         alert('Double Click');  //perform double-click action

                         clicks = 0;  //after action performed, reset counter

                         }
                  }
```